# How to test functionality across multiple application runs with Spring and JUnit5?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit5

My application does some nontrivial custom initialization, using the data from a database. I would like to make an integration test to test this behavior. It would:

1. Start the application
2. Interact with the application (e.g. register a user, simulate some user activity...)
3. Shut it down
4. Start it again
5. Verify that the application is initialized properly with respect to 2.

Since I am working with the Spring Boot framework, I do not need to actually restart the application, all I need is to destroy and re-create the beans that I want to test. However, any approach that I considered has some gruesome flaw.

1. The `@DirtiesContext` annotation as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15948370/1097451) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33165647/1097451):

This does not work for me, since I would have to have two different test methods. One to perform the above-mentioned step 2 and another one to perform step 5. The starting and shutting down of the application would be accomplished by annotating the test class with:

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_METHOD)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
```

But unfortunately in Junit5 it is [not possible to specify the order of tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40666230/1097451). So I cannot be certain that 2 is executed before 5.

I tried to annotate the first test method with `@BeforeAll` and `@BeforeEach`, but this somehow negates the effects of the `@DirtiesContext` annotation and the ApplicationContext does not get reset.

2. The manual use of `ApplicationContext`:

I would re-create the bean I am testing manually.

```
@Test
fun test(@Autowired applicationContext: ApplicationContext)
{
    simulateUserActionAsInStep2()

    val factory = applicationContext.autowireCapableBeanFactory
    factory.destroyBean(service)
    val reCreatedService = factory.createBean(Service::class.java)
    factory.autowireBean(reCreatedService)

    testServiceAsInStep5(reCreatedService)
}
```

Apart from not winning the beauty contest, this solution comes to me as brittle and potentially incorrect, since I am re-creating only a single bean. There may be other affected beans that need re-creating in order for the test not to give a false negative result.

3. The manual order solution

I could just butcher in some extra code to make the two methods do the things I want in a specified order:

```
@Test
fun testMethod1()
{
    // If this method is being executed as the first one
    if (serviceUntouched()) 
        simulateUserActionAsInStep2()
    else
        testServiceAsInStep5(reCreatedService)
}

@Test
fun testMethod2()
{
    testMethod1()
}
```

All in all, it seems like there are no good choices, yet this seems like a common enough problem. Am I missing some obvious solution?

Comment: Your test is not a Unit test. Thats why JUnit is giving you such a hard time. If you depend on order for your tests try something different (RestAssured, Cucumber, MockMVC, etc) which one will depend on your requirements and the nature of your app

Comment: TBH, I have never seen anyone start, stop, and restart the entire application within a single test class. Do you actually have a concrete need for that?

Comment: @SamBrannen Yes, I want to test that the application is properly initialized with a non-empty database.

Comment: Then why don't you simply execute some SQL setup scripts against the database as the `ApplicationContext` is loading? That should suffice.

Comment: @SamBrannen because I do not know how to do it. It seems that no matter what, by the time I am putting something into the database, the context is already initialized. Also, I would prefer to have a self-contained test rather than a test + script.

Comment: Spring Boot provides support for [automatically initializing your database](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc). You might also find [this article](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql) useful as a brief introduction.

Comment: If you really don't want to use SQL scripts or something like Liquibase or Flyway, I suppose your workaround for ordering the test methods would suffice until JUnit Jupiter has first-class support for ordering.